# Symfony with FOSUserBundle error while updating schema

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I follow this topic http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

I made steps 1-6 but when I must update database schema.

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get awful error.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE fos_user (id INT AUTO_I
NCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, username_canonical VARCH
AR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email_canonical VARCHAR(255)
NOT NULL, enabled TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, salt VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, passwor
d VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_login DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, locked TINYINT(1
) NOT NULL, expired TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, expires_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
confirmation_token VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, password_requested_at DATETIM
E DEFAULT NULL, roles LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)', credenti
als_expired TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, credentials_expire_at DATETIME DEFAULT NUL
L, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8 (username_canonical), UNIQUE INDEX UN
IQ_957A6479A0D96FBF (email_canonical), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER S
ET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was  t
oo long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

with error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t  
oo long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

I don't have idea how to fix it. Anyone can help?

Btw. I am using Symfony 3!

Comment: Here the issue reported on github https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1919 There's also explanation and possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
username_canonical VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

with

```
username_canonical VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL
```

and do the same with email_canonical

if you use Doctrine ORM entity you must set:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=191)
 */
private $usernameCanonical;
```

take a look into length=**191**